# How to detect exact record type of parent object in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I could get record and parent object details using lookup fields. But I am not able to get parent object record type.

Example : I am trying to get contact details and parent(company) details.

```
    search.lookupFields({
        type: 'contact',
        id: context.recordId,
        columns: ['entityid', 'customer.entityid', 'customer.companyname']
    });
```

It returns Contact entityid and customer - entityid & companyname.
I want customer type too. It can be Prospect, Lead, Customer or any valid types,
for partner or vendor I have to specify partner.entityid or vendor.entityid.

Anyway to identify which parent company contact has
something like this customer.recordtype

Answer (score 3):

In NetSuite, the term "Customer" is used for both a record *type* and a *stage* within the Customer type - which can be a little confusing.

Lead, Prospect and Customer are all stages, and this can be returned using `customer.stage` as a value in the `columns` parameter.  When you do this, it will be returned as an array of objects with `value` and `text` properties, so you would need to reference it like `<varName>['customer.stage'][0].value`.  **This only works if you know the *type* is `customer`** - otherwise the stage would be empty.

If the problem you're facing is actually to get the *record type* - IE: customer, vendor, partner etc, then you can instead use `company.type`.

Comment: Thanks Krypton for detailed explanation. i) How did you know these details? I could not find these details in doc or record browser. ii) I am getting company type as vendor for othername and details in vendor.* fields. Any idea?

Comment: I think I've seen the 'type' field in template examples - but I'm agreeing with Prabhu; I literally have no idea how to find out that 'meta' information.  See my answer below if you have access to the record object.

Answer (score 2):

look up `stage`

```
search.lookupFields({
    type: 'contact',
    id: context.recordId,
    columns: ['entityid', 'customer.entityid', 'customer.companyname', 'customer.stage']
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking for the customer.stage field?

Answer (score 0):

If you load the record, you can use the

```
recordObj.getRecordType()
```

apicall in suitescript 1.0, and

```
record.type
```

apicall in Suitescript 2.0.

Having said that, I was looking for information on the field so that I wouldn't have to load the whole record.  Perhaps available through nlapiLookupField (and its equivalent in 2.0).

```
var recTypeId = nlapiLookupField('contact', 'xxxxx', 'company.type', false)
```

This returns 'vendor' or 'customer' depending on what the contact refers to.  Presumably after determining this, you can lookup vendor fields by specifying 'vendor' as the type, or the field as 'vendor.field'